# SwiftUI Reload View

Tags: swiftui

I have a struct which shuffles and Lists records from CoreData.
I would like to reload / Refresh the List view with a Button.
I tried to use a function from within the Button.
Is there a way I can do this?

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        List {
            ForEach(dictionary.shuffled().prefix(upTo: 10),id: \.self) { word in
                HStack {
                    Text("\(word.englishWord)")
                        .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                    Text("| \(word.urhoboWord) |")
                        .foregroundColor(Color.green)
                    Image(word.imageName)
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width:40, height: 40)
                }//HStack
            }//End of ForEach
        }//End of List

        //Button to reload and shuffle list
        Button(action: {}) {
            Text("Shuffle")
                .padding()
                .background(Color.black)
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                .cornerRadius(6)
            }
        .navigationBarTitle(Text("Begin Learning"),displayMode: .inline)
```

Answer (score 13):

Just trigger any value of the `@State` or `@Published` of `@ObservableObject`.
If you do not have such, just create one:

```
@State var refresh: Bool = false

func update() {
   refresh.toggle()
}
```

Comment: Would add that where you put the state var may be relevant, if you have an object with objects or a view in a view -- had to go up one layer above the NavigationView to get the list to update, when a downstream detail view changed the text presented in the list.

Comment: It seems you also need to use the updated value in the view builder, otherwise the change will be ignored, e.g. `.background(Color.clear.disabled(refresh))`.

Comment: I suggest to use `@State private var id = UUID().uuidString`, `.id(id)` modifier on view that needs to be updated.

Answer (score 11):

You should move this `dictionary.shuffled().prefix(upTo: 10)` to your `ViewModel` and your view just reload base on the data.
Take a look at this code for reference:

```
struct SampleShuffleView : View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ShuffleViewModel
    
    var body : some View {
        VStack {
            List(self.viewModel.listData, id: \.self) { str in
                Text(str)
            }
            
            Button(action: self.shuffle) {
                Text("Shuffle me").padding()
            }.background(Color.white).padding()
            
        }
    }
    
    func shuffle() {
        self.viewModel.shuffle()
    }
}

class ShuffleViewModel : ObservableObject {
    @Published var listData = ["one", "two", "three", "four"]
    
    func shuffle() {
        listData.shuffle()
        //or listData = dictionary.shuffled().prefix(upTo: 10)
    }
}
```

Note: All view's components will be reloaded when `@ObservedObject` changes, so consider to separate smaller view-viewmodel(s), or using `@State` variable.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Think about. To show array and shuffle on tap, do exactly what you would like to see. first show us the array in some "list" like manner and next shuffle it on user action.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var arr = ["ALFA", "BETA", "GAMA", "DELTA"]
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
        VStack {
            Divider()
            ForEach(arr, id: \.self) { element in
                VStack {
                    Text(element)
                    Divider()
                }
            }
        }
            Spacer()
            Button(action: {
                self.arr.shuffle()
            }) {
                Text("Shuffle")
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

`arr.shuffle()` changed the `@State` of View and force SwiftUI to "reload it" automatically.

Comment: @Ahmadreza please, specify what doesn't work in your specific situation.

Comment: It does not force subviews to update in my case.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I just solved it

1 — Place this in your Extensions.swift (or anywhere, really)

```
class ReloadViewHelper: ObservableObject {
    func reloadView() {
        objectWillChange.send()
    }
}
```

2 — Then in the class that didn't update, add this variable.

```
@ObservedObject var reloadViewHelper = ReloadViewHelper()
```

3 — Then when You want your whole view to update, just call:

```
reloadViewHelper.reloadView()
```

Or like this

```
Button(action: { reloadViewHelper.reloadView() } ) {
    Text("Update View")
}
```