# SwiftUI: Update parent view on change of UserDefaults in child view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am making a game with a minimal color scheme. I store the colors that I use as computed `static var`'s in an enum so that I can call them in any view. I am trying to make a secondary color scheme (colorblind). My code looks like this:

```
enum GameColors {
    static var exampleColor: Color {
        !UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: GamePrefs.colorBlindMode) ? Color.green : Color(red: 0 / 255, green: 213 / 255, blue: 255 / 255)
    }
}
enum GamePrefs {
     static let colorBlindMode: String = "colorBlindMode"
}
```

My settings menu is called in my main menu view like so:

```
struct MainMenuView: View {
    @State var settingsClicked: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                settingsClicked.toggle()
            } label: {
                Text("Settings")
                .foregroundColor(GameColors.exampleColor)
            }
            if settingsClicked {
                SettingsView()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SettingsView: View {
    @AppStorage(GamePrefs.colorBlindMode) var colorBlindMode = false
    var body: some View {
        Toggle(isOn: $colorBlindMode) {
            Text("Color Blind Mode: \(colorBlindMode ? "On" : "Off")")
                .foregroundColor(GameColors.exampleColor)
        }
    }
}
```

When I toggle `colorBlindMode`, only `SettingsView`'s colors are updated, the color of the main menu does not change unless I interact with it. How do I get both to update?

I've tried binding the `@AppStorage` property wrapper to no success.

[image: Example]

Comment: Moving the contents of ```SettingsView``` into ```MainMenuView``` (so that both are using the same ```@AppStorage``` variable fixes the issue, but I'd rather have my code have good style

Comment: You could use the same `AppStorage` in your `MainMenuView`.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Would I need to put ```SettingsView``` inside of ```MainMenuView```to do what you said?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After reading a bit more about what causes SwiftUI to [reload a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59872397/swiftui-reload-view), and a whole lot of testing different methods, I believe that the simplest way to solve this problem is to introduce a new `@State` variable which you must use somewhere in the parent view:

```
struct MainMenuView: View {
    @State var settingsClicked: Bool = false
    @State var reloadView: Bool = false        // <-- here

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                settingsClicked.toggle()
            } label: {
                Text("Settings")
                .foregroundColor(GameColors.exampleColor)
            }
            if settingsClicked {
                SettingsView(reloadParentView: $reloadView)
            }
            if reloadView {}                   // <-- here
        }
    }
}

struct SettingsView: View {
    @Binding var reloadParentView: Bool        // <-- here
    @AppStorage(GamePrefs.colorBlindMode) var colorBlindMode = false
    var body: some View {
        Toggle(isOn: $colorBlindMode) {
            Text("Color Blind Mode: \(colorBlindMode ? "On" : "Off")")
                .foregroundColor(GameColors.exampleColor)
        }
        .onChange(of: colorBlindMode) { _ in
            reloadParentView.toggle()        // <-- here
        }
    }
}
```

Passing this state from the parent view to the child view allows the child to force reloads on the parent at will.

Comment: This entire problem is an example of why MVVM is so good for SwiftUI

Answer (score 2):

You could try this approach, using `@AppStorage` and `.onReceive` in `MainMenuView`,
to ensure `GameColors.exampleColor` is updated/received in the `MainMenuView` while
clicking in the `SettingsView`.

```
struct MainMenuView: View {
    @AppStorage(GamePrefs.colorBlindMode) var colorBlindMode = false  // <-- here
    @State var settingsClicked: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                settingsClicked.toggle()
            } label: {
                Text("Settings").foregroundColor(GameColors.exampleColor)
            }
            if settingsClicked {
                SettingsView() 
            }
        }
        .onReceive(Just(colorBlindMode)) { _ in  // <-- here
        }
    }
}

struct SettingsView: View {
    @AppStorage(GamePrefs.colorBlindMode) var colorBlindMode = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Toggle(isOn: $colorBlindMode) {
            Text("Color Blind Mode: \(colorBlindMode ? "On" : "Off")")
                .foregroundColor(GameColors.exampleColor)  // <-- here for testing
        }
        .toggleStyle(SwitchToggleStyle(tint: GameColors.exampleColor))
    }
}
```

Comment: add `import Combine` to you file, and it will work

Answer (score 2):

The reason your color does not change is because of your `MainMenuView` is not refreshing when you press the toggle. Only your `SettingsView` is refreshed. So you would need something to notify your `MainMenuView` that something has changed.

To do so you can add another AppStorage to your `MainMenuView` and force your view to refresh by creating a dependency on this property.

```
struct MainMenuView: View {
    @State var settingsClicked: Bool = false
    // add the same AppStorage as in SettingsView
    @AppStorage(GamePrefs.colorBlindMode) var colorBlindMode = false
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                settingsClicked.toggle()
            } label: {
                let _ = print("text")
                Text("Settings")
                    //this will force the view to update
                    .foregroundColor(colorBlindMode ? GameColors.exampleColor : GameColors.exampleColor)
            }
            if settingsClicked {
                SettingsView()
            }
        }
    }
}
```